# change a fraction of a column in a dataframe based on other information in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame

```
Person      Salary 
John         350
Peter        543
Susan        517
Carl         448
```

And I have this other dataframe with the changes that I have to make to the first

```
 Attribute    Change
  Person         3
  Salary         2
```

The value of **"Change"** should refer to changing the amount that appears by another letter, for example "x". The result should look like this:

```
   Person      Salary 
    Jxxx         3xx
    Pexxx        5xx
    Suxxx        5xx
    Cxxx         4xx
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Person':['John', 'Peter', 'Susan','Carl'],
'Salary':[350,543,517,448]})

change_df = pd.DataFrame({'Attribute':['Person', 'Salary'],
'Change':['3','2']})
```

The solution:

```
for col in df.columns:
    k = int(change_df[change_df.Attribute == col].Change)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:len(str(x))-k]+k*'x')
```

The result:

```
  Person Salary
0   Jxxx    3xx
1  Pexxx    5xx
2  Suxxx    5xx
3   Cxxx    4xx
```

Comment: looks like your final output differs from the intended output on rows 0 and 3, column 'Person'

Comment: I got it incorrectly, you are right. I am keeping first x letters, not replacing last x

Comment: Fixed. and took elements of your lambda, Thank you for the idea. I think a loop is easier to understand here

Comment: Another question, this function could be used for floating numbers?

Comment: str(x) instead of x. Done

Comment: @ Dennis Lyubyvy Another doubt, because when the value is "0" it deletes the whole column, as I could do so that if it finds the "0" it does not make any change.

Comment: @ Dennis Lyubyvy If I need to do a validation based on another column, so that I don't do it in all cases. Where would you recommend me to do it?

Comment: sorry I don't understand the question. Can you be more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A concise and elegant answer consists in first in creating a mapping from your `mapping_df`, and then apply a function following that mapping on your `target_df`.

You can get a mapping from your `mapping_df` with `transpose`

```
>>> mapping_df.transpose().to_dict()
{1: {'Attribute': 'Person', 'Change': '3'},
 2: {'Attribute': 'Salary', 'Change': '2'}}
```

And then just apply it to your `target_dataframe` using `map`

```
cleaned = pd.DataFrame()

for mapping in list(mapping_df.transpose().to_dict().values()):
    cleaned[mapping['Attribute']] = target_df[mapping['Attribute']].map(
        lambda s: s[: - int(mapping['Change']) ]+ int(mapping['Change']) *'x')
```

You will get the intended output

```
 >>> cleaned
    Person  Salary
1   Jxxx    3xx
2   Pexxx   5xx
3   Suxxx   5xx
4   Cxxx    4xx
```